# Extracting data from an iterator of Doc's

Tags: python, json, api, wrapper

I am using the yanytapi (https://pypi.org/project/yanytapi/) Python Wrapper for the New York Times Api. I managed to run my search and get data out in a JSON format running the following code:

```
obama = api.search("Obama", 
                          fq={"headline": "Obama", 
                              "source": ["Reuters", 
                                         "AP", 
                                         "The New York Times"]}, 
                          begin_date="20190701", # this can also be an int
                          facet_field=["source", "day_of_week"], 
                          facet_filter=True)
for item in obama:
    print(item)
```

The output looks like this:

> {"_id": "nyt://article/2c48c662-6053-562e-8187-88c954f5983f", "blog":
>   {}, "byline": {"original": "By Arit John", "person": [{"firstname":
>   "Arit", "middlename": null, "lastname": "John", "qualifier": null,
>   "title": null, "role": "reported", "organization": "", "rank": 1}],
>   "organization": null}, "document_type": "article", "headline":
>   {"main": "Obama Shares His Summer Reading List", "kicker": null,
>   "content_kicker": null, "print_headline": "Barack Obama Shares His
>   Reading List", "name": null, "seo": null, "sub": null}, "keywords":
>   [{"name": "subject", "value": "Writing and Writers", "rank": 1,
>   "major": "N"}, {"name": "subject", "value": "Books and Literature",
>   "rank": 2, "major": "N"}, {"name": "persons", "value": "Obama,
>   Barack", "rank": 3, "major": "N"}]....

I tried to extract the data and put it into a df running the following:

```
users_locs = [[article['_id'], article["document_type"]] for article in obama]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=users_locs, columns=['ID', 'type'])
df
```

But my dataframe is empty? Why? How can I extract it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation, the articles are `Doc` objects, to access the different fields yous should use the `.<field_name>` syntax like:

```
obama = api.search("Obama", 
                          fq={"headline": "Obama", 
                              "source": ["Reuters", 
                                         "AP", 
                                         "The New York Times"]}, 
                          begin_date="20190821", # this can also be an int
                          facet_field=["source", "day_of_week"], 
                          facet_filter=True)

users_locs = [[article._id, article.document_type] for article in obama]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=users_locs, columns=['ID', 'type'])
df
```

This are my results:

```
    ID  type 
 0  nyt://article/5722feb7-c751-50dd-ac84-85526e11...   article
 1  nyt://article/3577d507-ba57-5b9c-bcee-b1542650...   article
 2  nyt://article/9c2f0502-8264-5645-af44-d8656d5d...   article
 3  nyt://article/b55ca58d-dc0f-5f5f-a01c-178d2fc7...   article
 4  nyt://article/f3596774-562f-5c74-b62f-2c60f2d2...   article
 5  nyt://article/d783f1e3-26b3-561d-9455-5f2e035b...   article
 6  nyt://article/aa503b22-66ab-5796-a923-e3c99c79...   article
 7  nyt://article/41e68733-a47e-58bc-bbc8-f93397f2...   article
 8  nyt://article/98bc5831-3639-5abc-a339-3e1d74fc...   article
 9  nyt://article/ff30c8ef-bf58-5ce8-9d92-4b25a464...   article
```